# Authentication with Azure Management API

Tags: azure, rest, active-directory, azure-authentication

We have been using Azure API for some time for various operations. For example this is one of the APIs we use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces/createorupdate and as mentioned in the docs the URL that we send request to is:

> management.azure.com

Recently we have had the need to start performing against our Cloud Services via API. I noticed that the URL was different then what we have been using before --

> management.core.windows.net

as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-list-cloud-services

Firstly, could someone explain me the differences between those two?

Secondly, how can I authenticate against the management.core.windows.net using tenant/client/secret keys?

Here is the following code I have been using to auth with the first URL.

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Constants.AZURE_TENANT_ID}");
var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                        "https://management.azure.com/",
                        new ClientCredential(Constants.AZURE_MANAGEMENT_API_CLIENT, Constants.AZURE_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET)
                    ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
return result.AccessToken;
```

I tried to simply replace the URL but that did not work. I got the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could someone explain me the differences between those two?

Azure Resource Manager provider APIs use `https://management.azure.com/`, and Azure classic deployment model uses `https://management.core.windows.net/`

> how can I authenticate against the management.core.windows.net using
>   tenant/client/secret keys?

You should be able to get the access token if the settings are correct, you can try again.

[image]

Comment: What are you using after login.microsoftonline.com? seems like its something xxx.onmicrosoft.com vs mine is GUID looking tenant ID? I think we are using certification for auth instead of AD user if that makes a difference?

Comment: @scorpion5211 I am using the tenant name, tenant id will also be ok. Have you tried again?

Comment: Yeah no matter what I do still the same issue. I was informed that another developer had achieved this in other parts of the system so I am going to take a look at what he did and give final update then.

Comment: although I am voting for your answer as it seems like others had agreed that what you are suggesting should be working and I think I am just overlooking something.